# Omniauth + Devise Redirect Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth, facebook-iframe

I have the following problem: My app is running as a Facebook app, but on the first time that the user accept's it's Facebook permissions, it's redirected to the right URL, but outside the Facebook (canvas). How can I fix it?

Here is my actual settings:

devise.rb:`config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], scope: "email,publish_stream"`

app/controllers/omniauth_callback_controller.rb

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

      def passthru
      render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false
      end


      def facebook

        @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

        if @user.persisted?
          flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"

          sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
        else
          session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to root_path
        end
      end

      def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        inicio_path
      end
    end
```

routes.rb

```
Pl::Application.routes.draw do



      ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

      mount Resque::Server, :at => "/resque"

      devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

      devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" }

      devise_scope :user do
      get '/users/auth/:provider' => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru'
      end

      match 'states'  => 'game_plays#states'
      match 'cities'  => 'game_plays#cities'
      match 'parties' => 'game_plays#parties'
      match 'prefeito' => 'game_plays#prefeito'
      match 'prefeitos' => 'game_plays#prefeitos'
      match 'vereadores' => 'game_plays#vereadores'
      match 'parties' => 'game_plays#parties'
      match 'qualities' => 'game_plays#qualities'
      match 'start' => 'game_plays#start'
      match 'generated_image' => 'game_plays#generated_image'
      match 'save_game_play' => 'game_plays#save_game_play'
      match 'final' => 'game_plays#final', :as => :final

      match 'inicio'  => 'game_plays#index'  


      root :to => 'game_plays#bem_vindo'

    end
```

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is from my own experience a couple months ago with this issue and I hope it helps.

From Facebook's point of view, this is exactly what it is suppose to do.  It does not recognize the difference between where the request is coming from.  You have to change the redirect URL on the request for it to stay in the iframe.

The easiest way I found to do this was to have the iframe url go to my_website.com/fb-app, which sets a session variable to let you know you are in the canvas and ensures they are already logged in through facebook.  It then redirects them to the canvas site where the site continues as normal and the user never notices anything.

```
def fbapp

  session[:fbapp] = true

  if user_signed_in? == false
    redirect_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)
  else
    redirect_to $APP_CANVAS_URL + "?auth_token=" + current_user.authentication_token
  end
end
```

Then, in your Application_controller.rb you need to change the redirect path.  This is what it looked like in my application, note $APP_CANVAS_URL should be something along the lines of https://apps.facebook.com/your_app_here

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)  
  if session[:fbapp] == true
    $APP_CANVAS_URL + "?auth_token=" + current_user.authentication_token
  else
    root_path
  end
end
```

I doubt this is the best way, but it's what I got to work for me after hours of frustration.  I hope it helps.